# cloog and ppl error (graphite-ppl.c) in GCC 4.6.2 installation

Tags: gcc, gcc4

I'm trying to install gcc 4.6.2 with ppl and cloog in 64 bit ubuntu 10.10. I get the following error when I do make.

```
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/praveen/gcc-4.6.2/host-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/gcc'
/home/praveen/gcc-4.6.2/host-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/prev-gcc/xgcc -B/home/praveen/gcc-4.6.2/host-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/prev-gcc/ -B/usr/local/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ -B/usr/local/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/bin/ -B/usr/local/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/lib/ -isystem /usr/local/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/include -isystem /usr/local/x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/sys-include      -g -O2 -gtoggle -DIN_GCC   -W -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Wcast-qual -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-format-attribute -pedantic -Wno-long-long -Wno-variadic-macros -Wno-overlength-strings -Wold-style-definition -Wc++-compat   -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc  -o cc1 c-lang.o c-family/stub-objc.o attribs.o c-errors.o c-decl.o c-typeck.o c-convert.o c-aux-info.o c-objc-common.o c-parser.o tree-mudflap.o c-family/c-common.o c-family/c-cppbuiltin.o c-family/c-dump.o c-family/c-format.o c-family/c-gimplify.o c-family/c-lex.o c-family/c-omp.o c-family/c-opts.o c-family/c-pch.o c-family/c-ppoutput.o c-family/c-pragma.o c-family/c-pretty-print.o c-family/c-semantics.o c-family/c-ada-spec.o i386-c.o \
      cc1-checksum.o main.o  libbackend.a ../libcpp/libcpp.a ../libdecnumber/libdecnumber.a ../libcpp/libcpp.a   ../libiberty/libiberty.a ../libdecnumber/libdecnumber.a  -lcloog -lppl_c -lppl -lpwl -lgmpxx -lmpc -lmpfr -lgmp -rdynamic -ldl  -L../zlib -lz
libbackend.a(graphite-ppl.o): In function `ppl_powerset_is_empty':
graphite-ppl.c:(.text+0xd5d): undefined reference to `ppl_new_PIP_Problem_from_constraints'
graphite-ppl.c:(.text+0xd66): undefined reference to `ppl_PIP_Problem_is_satisfiable'
graphite-ppl.c:(.text+0xd71): undefined reference to `ppl_delete_PIP_Problem'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [cc1] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/praveen/gcc-4.6.2/host-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/gcc'
make[2]: *** [all-stage2-gcc] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/praveen/gcc-4.6.2'
make[1]: *** [stage2-bubble] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/praveen/gcc-4.6.2'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Can some one help me out on this ?

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem a while ago on my gentoo installation. The workarround was to build gcc without graphite option then to rebuild ppl and cloog-ppl libraries with a new version of gcc. Only after that gcc was successfully built with graphite.

Answer (score 0):

The problem, I believe, is that the ppl library libppl_c.so.4 is reported by `make` to be non-existent during the linking process -- even if the library has been installed to the standard /usr/local/lib directory successfully. Try reconfiguring with the flag `--with-ppl-lib`. I also included the flag `--with-ppl-include` and the corresponding cloog flags too (just to pre-empt any possible corresponding problems with cloog) because I didn't want to have to keep recompiling to discover exactly which flags I needed, so I played it cautiously and included all of these; maybe you also need them too, but probably not. Whilst you should be able to just use the flag `--with-ppl`, that will not work.

```
# I installed ppl and cloog to the standard subdirectories of /usr/local
# but you can amend the flag inputs as necessary 
tar xjf gcc-x.tar.bz2
mkdir build && cd build
../gcc-x/configure --with-ppl-lib=/usr/local/lib \
                   --with-ppl-include=/usr/local/include \
                   --with-cloog-lib=/usr/local/lib \
                   --with-cloog-include=/usr/local/include
```

Again, the issue is probably that the non-existence of the `--with-ppl-lib` flag is setting some internal `configure` variable incorrectly rather than there being a general linking issue with the library.